# RibbonToggleButton displays image badly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm using Ribbon from RibbonControlsLibrary.dll 4.0.0.11019, .NET 4.0, C#, WPF.
It can be downloaded with a free samples here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877

The problem comes when a `RibbonToggleButton` is displayed. Then it's image seems to be a little bit broken, like a part of image is shifted for a few pixels.

**EDIT**: Thanks to kind people I can post and image now:

[image: Same image for 1-line <code>RibbonToggleButton</code> and 2-line]

Here are some details:

1. Image is displayed in it's large variant
2. Image size is 32x32
3. I set image scaling to none for all the images of Ribbon
4. Image is broken only when the text in `RibbonToggleButton` has 1 line
5. Same image displays correctly in any other kind of button (`RibbonButton`, `RibbonSplitButton` etc.)
6. The image is displayed correctly when I set the font size in Windows to Medium (125%)
7. My OS is Windows 8
8. When I set the `VerticalContentAlignment` for the toggle button to "Bottom", the `Image` starts to display correctly, but the whole Ribbon starts to look ugly.

I experience this problem for all the toggle buttons, including those which are in a Microsoft's free samples.

I guess that probably the Image doesn't have enough space, so it's compressed from 32x32 to some smaller size.

I use the theme that is made of Microsoft's Generic theme, that is included in the RibbonControlsLibrary.dll. I guess I could fix the `RibbonToggleButton` template somehow, but I have no idea what to fix there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the xaml declaration of your UserControl / Window    put that line:

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Comment: … mhhh I had the same problem but works now…   add this line additionaly to the first one.    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"   and be sure to do that on the same window/userControl of your ribbon

Comment: Could you please explain what does that code actually do?

Comment: good question!  take a look here  [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions_attachedproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I don't know why those options aren't set by default… maybe because of silverlight